# Where to get interfaces for various DEX for smart contracts

Tags: solidity, router, contract

I am very new to smart contracts and am wondering,
if someone would be able to assist with a newbee question.

The following code snippet is part of a contract that swaps
tokens at various crypto exchanges.

I understand that I can get certain interfaces for
Sushiswap or UniSwap on Github.

However, where would I get the router address or token address
for other exchanges, such as Kraken or PancakeSwap from?

--

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import "./interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

contract Swaptoken { 
   // router addresses
   IUniswapV2Router01 private constant uniSwapRouter   = IUniswapV2Router01(0xE59242....61564);
   IUniswapV2Router02 private constant sushiSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(0x1b02dA....97506);

   // token addresses
   address private constant BNT = 0xF35cCfbcE1228014F66809EDaFCDB836BFE388f5;
   address private constant DAI = 0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D;

   .
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Kraken is not a decentralised exchange and does not have smart contracts
- PancakeSwap ABIs you can get from PancakeSwap website
- For any ABIs please follow the official documentation of the project

Comment: Thank you, Mikko. As I mentioned, I am pretty new to this and thought that, because I can swap ERC20 token such as DAI and ETH on any exchange that has the ethereum blockchain, including Kraken or Binance.

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of Ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug a transaction, using [tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer) for example.
Input in search transaction hash and you will get a lot of details for this transaction including addresses of contracts, methods, call data, etc..